# aspose cell exception this file format is not supported

Tags: java, json, aspose

I am using aspose cells to convert json file to excel file but getting an excpection saying that file format is not supported, Below is the code which i am using.Getting excepetion at the line **Workbook workbook = new Workbook(".//Json_files//elastic_search.json");**

```
public void FinBlock() throws Exception {

    String USERNAME = CONFIG.getProperty("Username");
    String Password = CONFIG.getProperty("password");
    String URI = CONFIG.getProperty("API");
    SessionFilter session = new SessionFilter();
    RestAssured.baseURI = URI;
    String Response = given().auth().preemptive().basic(USERNAME, Password).filter(session).when()
            .get(RestAssured.baseURI).then().extract().response().getCookie("RAY_SESSION_ID");

    Response resp1 = given().cookie("RAY_SESSION_ID", Response).filter(session).when()
            .get("URI")
            .then().log().all().extract().response();

    PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(
            new FileWriter(".//Json_files//elastic_search.json", true), true);
    out1.write(resp1.asString());
    out1.close();

    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String formattedDate = date.format(dateFormat);

    DateTimeFormatter dateformat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm");
    String formatedate = date.format(dateformat);

    Path dir = Paths.get(".//Output_Files//ES_Excelfiles-" + formattedDate);
    Files.createDirectories(dir);

    Workbook workbook = new Workbook(".//Json_files//elastic_search.json");
    // workbook.save(".//output-"+formatedate+".xlsx");
    // workbook.save(".//Excel_files//es_files//ES-"+stockname+"-"+formatedate+".xlsx");
    workbook.save(dir + "//ES-" + stockname + "-" + formatedate + ".xlsx");

}
```

Comment: There is a blog post from aspose about importing json data. It's based on the c# version of aspose.cells, but it might be helpful: https://blog.aspose.com/cells/import-data-from-json-to-excel-in-csharp-asp.net/

Comment: @SpaceTrucker am using java.

Comment: @Ramesh, please provide your "elastic_search.json" file/data to evaluate your issue. You may zip it and attach. You may also post your queries or issue in the dedicated forum(https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.